# how do i match input type values and mysql database row values

Tags: php, mysql, database, autocomplete, autosuggest

how do i match input type values and mysql database row values? if both values are shouldn't be match to each others then `echo A Message`?

**Main Page**

```
   $(function() {
   $( "#textname" ).autocomplete({
   source: "data.php",
   minLength: 1
   });
   });
   </script>


   <div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="Name">Name: </label>
   <input id="textname" class="textname"/>
   </div>
```

**Data Page**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")  or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("edgesoft", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$return = array();
$query = mysql_query("select * from customers where cname like '%$q%'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['cname'],'value'=>$row['cname']));
}

echo(json_encode($return));

if(json_encode($return))
{
echo "test";    
}
?>
```

Comment: Just so you know this code is wide open for SQL injections.

Comment: @blamonet this is not answer

Comment: Lets be the first - mysql_* library is deprecated

Comment: @FarhanAziz understood, this is why I submitted a comment instead of an answer. :)

Comment: .. And that was the second comment.

Comment: @blamonet ok sorry for that but soon i will correct it now can u you give me solution for my question?

Comment: @blamonet i'm using autocompleted/autosuggest textbox and values retrieve from database? but how can i apply if condition on autocompleted/autosuggest textbox values? when i put values into textbox it should be check the values into mysql database if text box values shouldn't be match into mysql database values then it should be give a message?? i have code and i tried but is not working?

Comment: first, you need to change like '%term%' to = 'term', then, if no rows found, return the message that you want

Comment: you can check using mysql_num_rows($query) if its greater than 0 then there is at least one row...

Comment: @akam you mean like this if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}